# Multiple style sheets

Tags: php, html, css

Very quick question. I am building a site and have the header and footer as PHP includes. Is there a way to have separate external stylesheets for the header, footer and index without one overriding the others.

Comment: You could either create different headers.php for example headers-style-1.php, headers-style-2.php etc or create one headers.php which will contain a switch or if statements checking for a global variable which is set on every page.php before calling header.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking, or rather, what your problem is. What have you tried? Add some code please.

Comment: sure there is; using unique id's for the "unique" stuff. Just use the related styles for each of them; however why would you want to use separate css files? you can also do an `@import` - but the question is rather broad/unclear as previously stated. If this is to be for different php files, then that is another ball of twine

Comment: you have answers below. If one of them answered the question, you can accept it to close the question.

Comment: I am obviously not getting through here; have you left the question or didn't get what you wanted?? Did you not try and solve this yourself first? One sticks around to offer help and they just say/do nothing.

Comment: Thanks. I will have a good look. As for "Chris" , please only post useful questions, if you don't understand the question please ask for clarification or please refrain from commenting.

Answer (score 0):

In your case You can try the following method:

**header.php**

```
<?php
//..some code 
$style = 'main.css'; 

?>
```

**somefile.php**

```
<?php
include 'header.php';

$style = 'xx.css'; 

?>
```

**index.php**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="<?=$style?>" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to have three different css files, one for each of (Header, Body and footer)  and the name of Ids and Classes must be unique.

Comment: How would multiple css files help? They would all still be loaded into the same document.

Comment: He could have a single css file but he must identify the Ids and the classes in the css file uniquely. @Turnip